# IllegalAccessError: ClassA and class B are in unnamed module of loader 'app'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring @Configuration bean which initializes a class A. This class A, in its constructor, calls another static method in class B. When spring initializes class A it eventually fails with
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class A tried to access method in class B (class A and classB are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

The class A and B are in present in different libraries, and I don't get any compilation issue at all.

Java version is 11, and the app uses spring boot 2.3.4-RELEASE.

I tried searching for answers but seem to find nothing on it.
Can somebody please assist here?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to the `module-info.java` did the trick for me:

```
requires spring.core;
requires spring.beans;
requires java.instrument;
```

Answer (score 0):

Class B is loaded by a jar which is coming as a transitive dependency to the project. Added the jar, which has class B, as a direct dependency solved the issue.